# Django Rest Framework Validation: Combining `required` errors from two fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to combine the errors thrown for a required field into a new property e.g. from this:

```py
{'start_date': 'This field is required', 'end_date': 'This field is required'}
```

to this:

```py
{'date': 'This field is required'}
```

At first I thought I could do the validation in the serializer's `validate` method, but it seems like this is only called after the `required` validation is performed. For example, the following doesn't work:

```py
class DatesRequiredSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        super().validate(data)
        # check if data is in either the request or instance
        start_date, end_date = None, None
        if 'start_date' in data:
            start_date = data['start_date']
        elif self.instance:
            start_date = self.instance.start_date

        if 'end_date' in data:
            end_date = data['end_date']
        elif self.instance:
            end_date = self.instance.end_date

        # this error isn't raised
        if not (start_date or end_date):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"date": _('This field is required.')})

        return data
```

Is it possible to combine the validations without setting the serializer fields to `required=False`?

*P.S. if there's a cleaner way to check if data is in the request / instance, would love to know too!*

Comment: I assume your model has field `start_date` and `end_date`, but no field `date`. You could override the `clean` method in the model and impelent there the validation logic.

Comment: Correction: implement, not impelent.

Comment: @cezar what I understood is the model's clean method will not be called by the DRF serializer unless you do it within the serializer's validate, which should be the same as above? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform

Answer (score 0):

Override `to_internal_value` of your `serializers.Serializer` to create custom errors and add them to the usual required exceptions.

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Becomes:

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "criteria_text": [
        "Either criteria_url or criteria_text is required"
    ],
    "criteria_url": [
        "Either criteria_url or criteria_text is required"
    ]
}
```

In my case the user needs to fill in either `criteria_text` or `criteria_url`, If they fail I want to tell them this at the same time they would get the usual required errors.

> ```
> def to_internal_value(self, data):
>     if data.get('criteria_text', None) is None and data.get('criteria_url', None) is None:
>         errors = OrderedDict([('criteria_text', [ErrorDetail('Either criteria_url or criteria_text is required')]),
>                               ('criteria_url', [ErrorDetail('Either criteria_url or criteria_text is required')])])
>         try:
>             super(MySerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
>             raise serializers.ValidationError(detail=errors)
>         except serializers.ValidationError as e:
>             e.detail = OrderedDict(chain(e.detail.items(), errors.items()))
>             raise e
>     else:
>         return super(MySerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
> ```